# C++ MultiDimensional Array with different data type at different places

Tags: c++

I created my own flowchart and I am following that. What stands as a problem for me is that I cant keep different data type at different places(for eg. the array is `arr[4][4]` then in `arr[3][1]` and `arr[4][3]` I want `char` and rest `int`)

What I want to try is in a multidimensional array, the first row, last row, first column, last column 4th and 8th both row and column to store '*' and rest numbers

I'm not sure if it is possible or not with templates or by any method.

Comment: you almost certainly dont need that

Comment: So, arrays are collections of multiple objects of the same type, so without tricks, you cannot and should not do that. As these things are not the same, separate them into different containers and create a structure/class out of them. Also: prefer vector or other STL containers to simple C arrays.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Indexing an array defined to be `arr[4][4]` with `arr[4][3]` breaks the array bounds. Valid index is `0..3`.

Comment: either make an array of classes/structs or an array of unions (to be more compact).. or use std::variant (since c++11 or 14 cant remember).

Comment: ... with `std::variant` being simply a type-safe union.

Comment: I'm old school I guess. :)

Comment: @Weather Vane  sry i didnt see that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger mind explaining me how this std::variant works?

Comment: @PrasinShrestha, Google is your friend.  It can help you find plenty of docs and probably even tutorials about `std::variant`.  If these leave you uncertain about it, then you could consider asking a separate question here.

Answer (score 3):

> What stands as a problem for me is that i cant keep different data type at different places(for eg. the array is arr[4][4] then in arr[3][1] and arr[4][3] i want char and rest int)

An array has one element type.  All its elements have that type, no other.

However, `char` is an integer data type, and every C++ implementation you are likely ever to see can accommodate every possible value of a `char` in an object of type `int`.  Therefore, it is safe, in practice, to store the value of a `char` in an array element of type `int`.  If you have done so and not subsequently modified that array element, then you can also read it back and store the value in a `char`.

(Do note, by the way, that there is a big difference between *one* `char` and an *array* of `char`, such as C uses for its strings.  We sometimes see confusion about that around here.)

More generally, though, you should be choosing appropriate data types.  If you have hetergeneous data that you want to treat as a unit, then you should be declaring a class to contain it, not using an array for that.

Comment: okay well i m trying to make a soduku game. i tried a simple sodoku without  borders and it worked but it looked kinda difficult to understand the game so i wanted to keep borders to help it look more better. thats why i created the game's display as a whole a single 2D array where i planned the 1st , last row , first column and last column as some kind of symbol as border similarly for bordering the 3x3 square boxes in the sodoku

Comment: @PrasinShrestha my advice dont mix data and the way you display data. The drawing method should add the borders. Keeping the borders in the data array is just a waste of memory, because presumably they never change value nor position in the array

Comment: @tobi303 thx..i almost forgot the graphics part. Thanks a bunch!